# Configure ubuntu cronjobs with offset and repeat it every 30 minutes

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'd like to run several jobs (until max. 4:30h).

1. Job: start at 02:00, run every 30 minutes
2. Job: start at 02:10, run every 30 minutes
3. Job: start at 02:20, run every 30 minutes
4. Job: start at 02:30, run every 30 minutes
5. Job: start at 02:40, run every 30 minutes
6. Job: start at 02:50, run every 30 minutes
7. Job: start at 03:00, run every 30 minutes
8. Job: start at 03:10, run every 30 minutes

The first one could be (but where to set the 4:30):

```
*/30 2-4 * * * myjob
```

The second could be imho (again, where to set 4:30):

```
10-59/30 2-4 * * * myjob
```

How to configure the those jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 16 cronjobs. You could use the `/` syntax ("every"), but I find the list easier to read for your use case.

---

[`0,30 2-4 * * * job1`](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_2-4_*_*_*)

---

[`10,40 2-3 * * * job2`](https://crontab.guru/#10,40_2-3_*_*_*)

[`10 4 * * * job2`](https://crontab.guru/#10_4_*_*_*)

---

[`20,50 2-3 * * * job3`](https://crontab.guru/#20,50_2-3_*_*_*)

[`20 4 * * * job3`](https://crontab.guru/#20_4_*_*_*)

---

[`30 2 * * * job4`](https://crontab.guru/#30_2_*_*_*)

[`0,30 3-4 * * * job4`](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_3-4_*_*_*)

---

[`40 2 * * * job5`](https://crontab.guru/#40_2_*_*_*)

[`10,40 3 * * * job5`](https://crontab.guru/#10,40_3_*_*_*)

[`10 4 * * * job5`](https://crontab.guru/#10_4_*_*_*)

---

[`50 2 * * * job6`](https://crontab.guru/#50_2_*_*_*)

[`20,50 3 * * * job6`](https://crontab.guru/#20,50_3_*_*_*)

[`20 4 * * * job6`](https://crontab.guru/#20_4_*_*_*)

---

[`0,30 3-4 * * * job7`](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_3-4_*_*_*)

---

[`10,40 3 * * * job8`](https://crontab.guru/#10,40_3_*_*_*)

[`10 4 * * * job8`](https://crontab.guru/#10_4_*_*_*)